# Where to put unit conversions (feet/meters/km) inside an MVVM application?

Tags: c#, mvvm

Where is the right place to put this class (Model/View/ViewModel)?
(note - currently the **View** uses that class)

```
public static class UnitsConvertor
{
    public enum Unit
    {
        Feet, Meters, KM
    }

    public static int Convert(Unit srcUnit, Unit destUnit, double value)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Edit**

More accuratyly, I wonder if the Model - i.e. the Business Logic - is the **only** place I can put on this code. Generally, can other layers contain static classes? (for instance - can ViewModel contain other classes which are **not** ViewModel?)

Comment: You can introduce new folder like: Common, Shared, Internal. All are valid options. In the MVVM architecture you have conventions for the model, viewmodel and view, but anything else is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For as far as the MVVM pattern is used, the views and models should actually just be dumb.
Views should only know what to show you and Models are just the data objects.

For placement it depends on how you want to structure your project. 
I would recommend something like a utility folder for a class like this.
Its a good place to put general functions like this one

Comment: In which layer should that folder reside? I wonder if the model is the **only** logical place for that folder

Comment: if you mean the utility folder i tend to put it on the same level as the model/viewmodel/view folders, not inside one of them. its not really a model because all it does is take data, use it and then return the result. but you can name the folder however you like, you could also call it a DataModel to separate it from the other models. but its up to you how to order it. as long as you are consistent and hold yourself to the rules you set yourself to.

Comment: can't agree with you 100% because "Unit" is a class which resides in Model, e.g. a part of the Data. In addition, isn't the whole structure of the code built from those 3 componnents?

Comment: Its mostly  personal preference. As long as you hold yourself to your rules you can order it the way you like. you could also write a base unit class and an extension to convert between them. so you dont need a static UnitsConverter.

Comment: That is interesting. In that case, do you suggest this base class to reside also outside the model? (because I believe this a part of "Data" also)

Comment: The base class would reside with the models for me. it would be a Data Object and that is what models are supposed to be. if you want to want to go more extreme you could place the enum separately in a data folder, taking the static 'Data' out of the model.